# Saving the PuTTY session logging

Tags: putty

I am using PuTTY for logging in to Solaris/Linux servers.

Under Sessions → Logging, we see 'Session Logging' settings. I am not able to save the settings for permanent use.

Isn't such feature available or am I wrong somewhere?

PS: I want to save the log file path, 'All session output' as a 'forever setting'.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It works fine for me, but it's a little tricky :)

- First open the PuTTY configuration.
- Select the session (right part of the window, *Saved Sessions*)
- Click <kbd>Load</kbd> (now you have loaded *Host Name*, *Port* and *Connection type*)
- Then click *Logging* (under *Session* on the left)
- Change whatever settings you want
- Go back to *Session* window and click the *Save* button

Now you have settings for this session set (every time you load session it will be logged).

Comment: This temporarily solves the problem, but this is not a global setting for the whole of Putty.

Comment: I don't understand.  This setting is for each session you save. Every session can have unique settings.

Comment: This method works for saved sessions only. If you directly enter the host name (IP), this doesn't hold.
In other words, every session should be saved and then loaded

Comment: Save to 'Default Settings'.  http://serverfault.com/questions/12295/how-to-make-putty-settings-persistent  The default session is loaded automatically :)

Answer (score 17):

I always have to check my cheatsheet :-)

Step 1: right-click on the top of putty window and select 'Change settings'.

[image]

Step 2: type the name of the session and save.

[image]

That's it!.
Enjoy!

Comment: My god.. i couldnt figure out in my life, how do I save a session configuration with hostname and port info for quick access.. this was it, the moment of enlightenment!

Answer (score 7):

To set permanent PuTTY session parameters do:

1. Create sessions in PuTTY. Name it as "**MyskinPROD**"
2. Configure the path for this session to point to "**C:\dir\&Y&M&D&T_&H_putty.log**".
3. Create a Windows "**Shortcut**" to C:...\Putty.exe.
4. Open "Shortcut" **Properties** and append "**Target**" line with parameters as shown below:

   ```
   "C:\Program Files (x86)\UTL\putty.exe" -ssh -load MyskinPROD user@ServerIP -pw password
   ```

Now, your PuTTY shortcut will bring in the "**MyskinPROD**" configuration every time you open the shortcut.

Check the screenshots and details on how I did it in my environment:

http://www.evernote.com/shard/s184/sh/93ebf08f-fde2-4dad-bccf-961c98fb614b/983d2ff8f2d1e6184318825d68b0b829

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit confusing, but follow these steps **to save the session**.

1. Category -> Session -> enter public IP in Host and 22 in port.
2. Connection -> SSH -> Auth -> select the .ppk file
3. Category -> Session -> enter a name in Saved Session -> Click Save

**To open the session**, double click on particular saved session.